# React localhost:3000 Not Working after restarting the pc

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and started learning it recently. Last day I created my 1st app and I was able to see it in the localhost:3000 before taking a break I bookmarked the page and shut down my pc.
Now when I try to access localhost:3000 it show me that it cannot connect. So I tried to use the "npm start" command in visual studio code terminal. But I received several errors and still trying to figure out how to start again the development server.
Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: What are those errors?

Comment: 35 error Missing script: "start"
35 error
35 error Did you mean one of these?
35 error     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
35 error     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
35 error
35 error To see a list of scripts, run:
35 error   npm run
36 verbose exit 1

Comment: Can you try `npm run start`

Comment: Please share your package.json, which is where the scripts are located. And make sure you're executing the command from the root folder of the project. Oh and @kiranvj may be right, maybe you're missing the "run" part.

Comment: same error even using this code

Comment: Inside package.json I have only this
`{
  "dependencies": {
    "tar": "^6.1.11"
  }
}
`

Comment: This is not the correct package.json. How did you create the react app? Is it via [CRA](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app) ?

Comment: I created the react app using the visual studio termina. Using the Quick start codes provided in the react documentation using
`npx create-react-app my-app 
cd my-app 
npm start`

Comment: This is correct , can you try again and check the `package.json` . After restarting computer check `package.json` again. If the file is different, there is something messing the React installation.

Comment: Also check this bug report [Create-React-App project not starting after system restart](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7077)

Comment: Solved the problem thx for pointing me on the right road saying about package.json react created 2 of them one inside the project root and one inside the my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The fact is that react created inside the project a folder called js inside it there is a package.json that has this small code

```
{
  "dependencies": {
  "tar": "^6.1.11"
  }
}
```

when i restarted the visual studio my location in terminal was inside the js folder so when I was trying to run the npm start command it wasn't working.
The fact is that react creates also another folder called my-app inside this one there is another package.json file. So in my case the solution was to move inside the my-app folder using cd. Attention the - symbol how spaces cannot be freely used inside the terminal. So the right way to navigate inside was

```
cd 'my-app'
```

if you don't use the quotes it will throw an error. now that I was inside the real app folder I was able to start the server using

```
npm start
```

This is a little bit strange and react devs need to add this fact in the documentation. Considering it automatically creates 2 folders and 2 package.json files making it confusing for newbie people like me